# Admin roles role_type table column

Tags: admin, magento2, magento-1, acl, role

In the `admin_role` table there is a column `role_type` that can have 2 values:

- 'G' - `Mage_Admin_Model_Acl::ROLE_TYPE_GROUP`
- 'U' - `Mage_Admin_Model_Acl::ROLE_TYPE_USER`

By their names I jump do the conclusion that one is for user roles, and the other is for group roles but I cannot understand how are these values used.
AFAIK each admin user, in order to have access to some admin areas must have a role. Is that role 'the group'? If yes, then what is the use of the `U` value. If not, what's 'the group' then?

Magento version is not important. It's been there since the "big bang" (v0.7) and it's even ported in the next universe (Magento 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the  that is 'the group'. Each user has a User Role which has a parent of a Group Role, all users are assigned to a group via the parent_id in that table.

The only real value I can see is in the acl generation where they can dump in the whole table and generate the acl structure based on the information provided, in Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_Acl::loadRoles

```
public function loadRoles(Mage_Admin_Model_Acl $acl, array $rolesArr)
{
    foreach ($rolesArr as $role) {
        $parent = ($role['parent_id'] > 0) ? Mage_Admin_Model_Acl::ROLE_TYPE_GROUP . $role['parent_id'] : null;
        switch ($role['role_type']) {
            case Mage_Admin_Model_Acl::ROLE_TYPE_GROUP:
                $roleId = $role['role_type'] . $role['role_id'];
                $acl->addRole(Mage::getModel('admin/acl_role_group', $roleId), $parent);
                break;

            case Mage_Admin_Model_Acl::ROLE_TYPE_USER:
                $roleId = $role['role_type'] . $role['user_id'];
                if (!$acl->hasRole($roleId)) {
                    $acl->addRole(Mage::getModel('admin/acl_role_user', $roleId), $parent);
                } else {
                    $acl->addRoleParent($roleId, $parent);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

It looks like they could have used ($role['parent_id'] > 0) to determine whether it is a group or user role, but I guess that is quite error prone.

Answer (score 4):

In short: What you call "the role" is the group (like "Administrators").

Each group has an entry with the type `G` and each user has an entry with the type `U` which refers to the user's group via `parent_id`. All access rules are defined at group level. If you look at the table `admin_rules`, you will see that all entries have `G` as role type.

The `admin_rule.role_type` feature seems to be something like the `stock_id`, somehow intended, never fully implemented and then carried along because nobody dares to touch it.

Out of curiosity I tried to enter a dataset with role type `U` manually but the parent role always takes precedence, no matter if it is an `allow` or `deny` rule. And without a parent role, you don't get access to the admin panel at all.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.x DB mysql query

SELECT au.user_id,au.username,au.firstname,au.lastname,au.email,CASE WHEN au.is_active = 1 THEN 'Enable' ELSE 'Disable' END AS Status ,au.created, au.logdate, detail_role.role_name FROM `admin_user` as au LEFT JOIN authorization_role as user_role ON au.user_id = user_role.user_id AND user_role.parent_id != 0 LEFT JOIN authorization_role as detail_role ON user_role.parent_id = detail_role.role_id