# magento 2 can anyone tell me how to get user permissions list from database . I need query for this .Please help me

Tags: magento2, query

Query to get user permissions list in magento2

[Admin roles role_type table column](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/admin-roles-role-type-table-column)

I found related query in above link but permission column is missing . Permission column exists in authorization rule table. So I am stuck with joining the table . So please anyone tell me the query to retrieve all user permissions list from database.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to link table to another
here i'm using inner join to link the table authorization_rule with authorization_role table
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

If you are looking to get the permissions throw db here is the query you need

```
SELECT arule.role_id, arole.role_name, arule.resource_id, arule.permission 
FROM authorization_rule as arule 
INNER JOIN authorization_role AS arole 
ON arule.role_id = arole.role_id 
where arole.role_id = <Enter the role id here>;
```

You can get and modify user permissions throw the BO of magento 2 on

> System > Permissions > User Roles > select the role > tab Role Ressources

[image: Way to get to role permissions : System > Permissions > User Roles, select the role > tab Role Ressources]

If you need a way to get the permission list throw code let me know.

Comment: Okay thank you for the response . Definitely I will try this